# Ionic Back Button Go to Previous Page with Query String

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic app, I faced a problem where I'm on Page A going to Page B with query string ex:

> Page A: #/app/channels-inside?id=30
>
> Page B: #/app/nowplaying

This is where the problem lies. When I click the back button it goes back to the correct page but without the query string (URL becomes **#/app/channels-inside**.  How do I handle this where I want to redirect to previous page with the id in it?

Answer (score 0):

This cant be achieved with default `pop()` method as its action is limited to popping the component from navigation array. What you can do is use `insert` and `remove` functions of `NavController`. Insert `channel-inside` in the navigation stack with the params you want. Then remove `now-playing` and already existing`channel-inside`.

`insert(insertIndex, page, params, opts)`

> Inserts a component into the nav stack at the specified index. This is
>   useful if you need to add a component at any point in your navigation
>   stack.

`remove(startIndex, removeCount, opts)`

> Removes a page from the nav stack at the specified index.

Check out the [docs.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)

**Edit**

Or you could use `Events` to pass the `params`

```
constructor(public events: Events) {}

// in now-playing
function createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}

// in channel inside
events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
  // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
  console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use it.

AngularJS: $ stateParams

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams){
    $stateParams.id
})
```

Comment: what controller where i'll put this? contoller of A or B?

Comment: Let me clarify your question, you have a query string in A, into the B and then return to A, will lose the original A query string, so right?